# VB.net - Dynamic database connection combobox

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, combobox

I have some code which populates a combobox with database names. I then have a button which saves the name back to My.Settings and creates the connection string.

This is working for the most part. If i select a database it will display the correct information for that database in my form, then if i go back out to my database selector and do the same it will still display the correct settings.

The problem is, i have a reload datagridview sub which re-populates the grid. If i select a database and then drop back out and pick another and then run the reload sub it pulls the settings from the other database. Even though when it initially launches it has the correct database information in the form.

I've tried My.Settings.Reset and My.Settings.Save to no avail.

Here's a snippet of code:

```
Dim strDatabase As String = My.Settings.Database
Dim strDatabaseCon As String = My.Settings.DatabaseCon

Public Sub Loadcombobox()
    My.Settings.Reset()
    My.Settings.Save()
    Try

        Dim con As New SqlConnection(" Data Source=******\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog =" & strDatabase & "; Integrated Security=true")
        con.Open()
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("Select * From sys.databases Where database_id > 4", con)
        Dim read As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        While read.Read()
            ComboBox1.Items.Add(read.Item(0))
        End While
        con.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    If ComboBox1.Text = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please select a customer")
    Else


        My.Settings.Database = ComboBox1.Text

        strDatabase = My.Settings.Database

        My.Settings.DatabaseCon = "Data Source=******\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog =" & strDatabase & "; Integrated Security=true"

        'Here we redeclare the strDatabaseCon = My.Settings.DatabaseCon
        strDatabaseCon = My.Settings.DatabaseCon

        My.Settings.Save()

        Mainform.Show()
        Me.Hide()
    End If
End Sub
```

This sub is on a different form and causes the datagridview to populate from the first database.

```
Sub ReloadRecords()
    Try
        FillDataGrid("SELECT * FROM Change_Control order by [DateOfChange] desc", dgvData)
        dgvData.Columns(0).Visible = False
        dgvData.Columns(1).Width = 200 ''Date of Change''
        dgvData.Columns(1).HeaderCell.Value = "Date Of Change"
        dgvData.Columns(2).Width = 200 ''Name''
        dgvData.Columns(2).HeaderCell.Value = "Who Made the Change"
        dgvData.Columns(3).Width = 470 ''Change made''
        dgvData.Columns(3).HeaderCell.Value = "Change Made"
        dgvData.Columns(4).Visible = False
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, Me.Text)
    End Try

End Sub
```

This is the FillDataGrid Function

```
Dim strDatabaseCon As String = My.Settings.DatabaseCon
Public Function FillDataGrid(ByVal Sqlstring As String, ByVal MyDataGrid As DataGridView)
    Dim SQLCon As New SQLConnection(strDatabaseCon)
    Dim SQLAdapter As New SqlDataAdapter()
    Dim myDataset As New DataSet()

    SQLCon.Open()

    Try
        SQLAdapter.SelectCommand = New SqlCommand(Sqlstring, SQLCon)
        SQLAdapter.Fill(myDataset)
        MyDataGrid.DataSource = myDataset.Tables(0)
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try

    SQLCon.Close()
    SQLAdapter.Dispose()
    myDataset.Dispose()
    Return True
End Function
```

Comment: I'm finding it very difficult to follow your question. We probably need to see the selected index change event of the combo, and probably FillDataGrid too. Tip: use SqlConnectionStringBuilder to prevent errors and security issues.

Comment: Hi @Crowcoder I dont have a selected index change event it just pulls it from `My.Settings.Database = ComboBox1.Text` do i need to have a selected index change? See original for the FillDataGrid function

Answer (score 0):

Not quite a fix but it gets around my problem.

The issue was my FillDataGrid function. not sure what part of it, but i created a new function and it now doesn't fill the grid with the database of the previous selected one.

```
 Public Sub DisplayRecords()
    Try
        Dim da = New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * from Change_Control order by [DateOfChange] desc", strDatabaseCon)
        dsetAssets = New DataSet
        da.Fill(dsetAssets, "Change_Control")
        dgvData.DataSource = dsetAssets.Tables("Change_Control").DefaultView
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, Me.Text)
    End Try

End Sub
```